# Turning off filter via pygsheets/python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

Just realized that pygsheets Worksheet.clear() + pasting dataframe to cleared worksheet, skips the filtered rows. Any hints on how to turn off filtering via pygsheets, or any other ways to overcome this:

*Worksheet with old data:*

**A | B**

old1 | old2 | - visible

old3 | old4 | - hidden

---

*Worksheet after Worksheet.clear()*

---

**A | B**

old3 | old4 | - hidden

---

*Worksheet after pasting dataframe:*

**A | B**

new1 | new2

old3 | old4 - hidden

new3 | new4

Thanks,